# Text is not being inserted in the file

Tags: c

I am trying to open a file and write to it.
Whenever I run the program, it creates the `textfile.txt` but it's empty. How do I deal with this?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char buf[1024];

    int file = open("testfile.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644);
    strcpy(buf, "My message");

    write(file, buf, sizeof(buf));

    close(file);
}
```

Comment: The most important bug here is the parameter sizeof(buf) in the call of write(). It can cause an unexpected result, including a crash because you try to access 1024 bytes but only the first 19 ones are valid ("My message is here", with the ending '\0').

Comment: you forget the `#include<unistd.h>` header file which contain the `close();` function.

Comment: The cycle is quite strange too, it does nothing other than clutter the code.

Comment: How do I get this to work then?

Comment: Edited my post to new code, still wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char buf[1024];

    int file = open("testfile.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644);
    strcpy(buf, "My message");

    write(file, buf, strlen(buf));

    close(file);
}
```